# polygon Class Java

Tags: java, 2d, physics

So I am looking at this 2-D physics impulse engine and I really like to know what is going on in each part of the code. There is one part that I am not understanding at all in the polygon class that defines a polygon.

Here is the link to the code:
https://github.com/ClickerMonkey/ImpulseEngine/tree/master/src/org/magnos/impulse

click on the polygon class and scroll down to the method named public Shape clone(). In this method there is "p.u.set( u );". I am not understanding what the meaning of this is at all or what it even does. I would be grateful for anyone that could explain what this single line in the code is doing.

thanks for reading

Comment: Instead of linking to the code, kindly copy the relevant parts here.

Comment: Sorry. Ill keep that in mind for next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by understanding that `Polygon` extends `Shape`...

```
public class Polygon extends Shape
```

In `Shape`, it defines `u` as `public final Mat2 u = new Mat2();`.

So, in `Polygon#clone`, it first creates a new instance of a `Polygon` and the sets this new instance's `u` object with the current instance of `u`...

```
Polygon p = new Polygon();
p.u.set( u ); // or p.u.set( this.u ); if it's easier to understand...
```

Now, in `Mat2`, the `set(Mat2)` method simply copies the properties of the parameter to those of it's own values...

```
public void set( Mat2 m )
{
    m00 = m.m00;
    m01 = m.m01;
    m10 = m.m10;
    m11 = m.m11;
}
```

So, basically, what this is doing is copying the properties of the parent `Polygon.u` (`Mat2`) to the child/cloned version...

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I saw the public final Mat2 u = new Mat2(); and thought it had something to do with that, just wasn't quite sure exactly how. That was driving me crazy for a while. Thanks for your time, much appreciated.